# Catalog Listing Widget - We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content

Tags: magento-2.1, widget, category-listing

When I want to use the Catalog Listing Widget I get the following message on the front page:  `"We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content."`
Can anybody help me out with this problem?

This is the code which was created by Magento. I'm using the community **edition 2.1.14**

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" title="f" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:2:`45`;]]"}}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you just un comment ini_set('display_errors', 1); from app/bootstrap.php then check browser you will get exact error ?

Comment: sadly it's not showing anything.

Comment: can you run command php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer then check ?